# Book about a young woman who was a warrior and a princess, who was accompanied by a magical talking cat that she carried around in a bag

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for the title of a book that I read in the late '80s or early '90s.  It was about a young woman who was a warrior and a princess with magic. She wore her hair in braids.

She was accompanied by a magical cat that she carried in a bag.  The cat could speak to her and one time shapeshifted into a cloud cat.

She was also accompanied by a group of warriors on of which was actually from the race of her enemies. I believe they were called Tallahat or something like that.

Comment: What does a "cloud cat" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Sabriel by Garth Nix. It was written in 1995 I think. It is the first in the Old Kingdom series which was released in the 2000's.

The cat that travels with her is called Mogget and is actually some sort of spirit or demon that is kept trapped as a cat by the collar he wears. Mogget is extremely lazy and often gets into Sabriel's backpack, sometimes even cutting it open (with his claws) to get in.

She is actually an Abhorsen which is a kind of necromancer, but instead of raising the dead she puts the dead back where they belong. She can also perform Charter magic and is a skilled sword fighter.

I can't remember at the moment if she is technically a princess but I think she is vaguely related to the royal family at least, but she does become queen of the Old Kingdom.

Comment: Did she carry the cat around in a bag?

Comment: @LogicDictates It certainly gets in her backpack, I'll add that in.

Comment: @LogicDictates Did the cat shape shift and was there a race called Talahat or something like that.  It is one thing I remember clearly from the book.

Comment: @janice The cat turns back into its Free Magic form when its collar is removed. I don't remember a race called the Talahat but I'll check.

Comment: I can't find any reference to talahat or similar in the book. The nearest I can think of is Touchstone, who is the future king.

Comment: Touchstone's real name is [Torrigan](https://oldkingdomwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Torrigan), and he's the half-brother of one of the villains, if that helps.There's also a character called Terciel and a place called Ancelstierre.